# roscpp: Node doesn't stop totally

Tags: c++, ros-melodic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I am trying to exit my C++ node correctly but the process doesn't exit totally, here's the log I get :

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.12
 * /sekonix_camera_ut/calib_dir_path: /home/nvidia/cros...
 * /sekonix_camera_ut/config_path: /home/nvidia/cros...
 * /sekonix_camera_ut/framerate: 30

NODES
  /
    sekonix_camera_ut (sekonix_camera_ut/sekonix_camera_ut_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [11422]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 8ad859d8-7c5a-11ec-8688-00044bf6558a
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11441]
started core service [/rosout]
process[sekonix_camera_ut-2]: started with pid [11444]
[sekonix_camera_ut-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/nvidia/.ros/log/8ad859d8-7c5a-11ec-8688-00044bf6558a/sekonix_camera_ut-2*.log
```

And after that the process hangs and doesn't exit.

And here's the C++ code :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "sekonix_camera_ut");
  ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
  return 0;
}
```

Any idea why the node hangs and doesn't exit ?

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394879/roscpp:-node-doesn%27t-stop-totally/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2022-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @gvdhoorn for finding the solution.

I used roslaunch to start the node without `required="true" which means that` roslaunch` did not exit.

---

Originally posted by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) with karma: 196 on 2022-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1